# Custom Routing with symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to extend symfony's default router. I have created routing folder in lib/ and created customRouter.class.php saved it under lib/routing. I have changed factories.yml as below:

```
all:
  routing:
    class: customRouter
```

My customRouter.class.php is:

```
class customRouter extends sfPatternRouting{
}
```

I only extend **sfPatternRouting** class. When I run the application it gives me an error as below:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to sfRouting::__construct() must be an instance of sfEventDispatcher, string given in /opt/task/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRouting.class.php on line 32
```

I do not realize the problem. I only extend the class. What is the solution to extend symfony's router?

Comment: Custom routing in symfony 1.4 is covered in the [Advanced Routing](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing) section of the the symfony book. Specifically, the section on [Creating a Custom Route Class](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing#chapter_02_creating_a_custom_route_class) should be helpful.

Comment: @Kenny I have checked that article but it is useless for me. Because I do not use doctrine. That article is extending sfDoctrineRoute. I have to extend sfPatternRouting but I can not.

Comment: I am using symfony 1.4.11 and I did the same thing like you did: routing folder in lib, empty customRouter class, changed settings in factories.yml, cleared cache - No problem, maybe your problem does not have to do with the customRouter class itself?

Comment: Just debug what exactly do You have in the variable just before its used in constructor, iam sure You have to trace where the problem begins.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are extending the wrong class and as such are not inheriting necessary methods. The symfony 1.4 documentation suggests extending the 'sfDoctrineRoute' class to create custom routing (as linked by @Kenny)